# How to put together 4 while loops of triangles to make a "diamond"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I want to make this "diamond":

```
********************
*********  *********
********    ********
*******      *******
******        ******
*****          *****
****            ****
***              ***
**                **
*                  *
*                  *
**                **
***              ***
****            ****
*****          *****
******        ******
*******      *******
********    ********
*********  *********
********************
```

I can make the 4 triangles that make the diamond using while loops:

```
x = 10
while 0 < x < 11:
    print '%10s' % ('*' * x),
    x = x - 1
    print

x = 0
while x < 11:
    print '%10s' % ('*' * x),
    x = x + 1
    print

x = 10
while 0 < x < 11:
    print '%0s' % ('*' * x),
    x = x - 1
    print

x = 0
while x < 11:
    print '%0s' % ('*' * x),
    x = x + 1
    print
```

Can I bring together these 4 while loops to make the diamond? Or do I have to do it a different way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you do it using string formatting (you can experiment with the parameters):

```
a = range(0,20,2)+range(20,-1, -2)

for i in a:
    print '{:*^30}'.format(' '*i)

[OUTPUT]
******************************
**************  **************
*************    *************
************      ************
***********        ***********
**********          **********
*********            *********
********              ********
*******                *******
******                  ******
*****                    *****
******                  ******
*******                *******
********              ********
*********            *********
**********          **********
***********        ***********
************      ************
*************    *************
**************  **************
******************************
```

What the code above does is it first creates a list `a` that contains the number of spaces for each of the lines. Then the string formatting prints a line for each element in the list of length `30` (the 30 part of `{:*^30}` which is centered `^` and padded on either sides with `*`. Hope that helps.

#### Or just for fun: one-linered:

`for i in range(1,20,2)+range(19,-1, -2):print '{:*^30}'.format(' '*i)`

Comment: Clever, but you really do need to explain why this works (I understand it fine, but many people won't know what the `*^30` format *does* here).

Comment: And you could also add a version with two `while` loops to match what the OP was looking for themselves.

Comment: Very nice, I will use this method instead, thank you very much.

Comment: @user2357, Well glad I could help!

Comment: @SundarNataraj, 3 if you remove that unnecessary blank line. :)

Comment: How can I learn to be more concise and efficient? I write like 20 lines for something what can be done with 1 line...

Comment: @user2357, OH! Sorry. Just realized that was a question :P. I'd say one of the best ways would be to browse the python tag here on stackoverflow at least it worked for me. You really learn some unique stuff here that you'd be hard put to find somewhere else. :)

Comment: @sshashank124 Thank you very much sshashank, I was thinking about doing through them because as you said there are things there that can't be found any where else. Also, at this point, I don't thing a textbook will help me anymore.

Comment: @user2357, Everything has limits. Textbooks were written at a time and help develop the foundations. To get to that next level, you have to experiment.

Comment: @sshashank124 think*

Yes, you are right. I want to get involved in open source projects so that I can practice more, experiment with new things and learn more but I think I need to learn a lot more basic things before being able to get into open source software dev.

Comment: @user2357, Find a group of friends that share similar interests to yours in terms of programming. Work on a project together. Like a multiplayer game or something. Best way to learn is to try/fail/learn and then succeed. I wish you the best of luck. Everyone has their own approaches.

Comment: @sshashank124 Thank you very much, really appreciate your help. A multiplayer game sounds like a good and challenging project, will hopefully attempt doing that!

Answer (score 1):

A very straightforward way is to use two loops:

```
def diamond(n):
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        print '*' * i + (' ' * (n-i) * 2) + '*' * i
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print '*' * i + (' ' * (n-i) * 2) + '*' * i
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I like this too very much. You can do it in one line too :D

    for i in range(10, 0, -1)+range(2, 11): print '*' * i + (' ' * (10-i) * 2) + '*' * i